# How can I test whether an email was sent using mocha?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js, supertest, superagent

I'm using NodeJS (specifically the SailsJS framework), and am sending an email upon creating a user. I want to verify in a Mocha test case that creating a user sends an email.

I can include something in the JSON response that states whether an email was sent and verify it in that response, but is there a better way? Perhaps some way to intercept the email and verify it?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are sending the email?

Comment: I'm using [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer). They have some usage examples in their docs.

I want to test it by triggering an API call, e.g. `POST /api/sendEmail`

Comment: Ok, so in principle you will need to design your code so you can inject the mailer into your API, and then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-mock-transport. If you post the code where you are sending the actual mail, I can show you how to either write a test for it, or refactor your code so that you can write a test for it.